# How to get how many key inside a gson object model class android?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a response that will look like this:

```
    "field_1":{
        
    },
    "field_2" : {
        "array_2": [
            {
                ... all other fields
            }
        ],
        "array_1": [
            {
               ... all other fields
            }
        ],
        // here will have 4 array or 5 array, I want to get how many array is inside this object
    },
    "field_3":{

    }
```

So I make my POJO class look like this:

```
public class MyPojo{

    @SerializedName("field_1")
    @Expose
    private Field1 class1;


    @SerializedName("field_2")
    @Expose
    private Field2 class2;

    @SerializedName("field_3")
    @Expose
    private Field3 class3;

    // other getter and setter 
}
```

Then I will have a `Field2` class that look like this:

```
public class Entities {

    @SerializedName("array_1")
    @Expose
    private List<Array1Item> arraylist1 = null;
    @SerializedName("array_2")
    @Expose
    private List<Array2Item> arraylist2 = null;

    @SerializedName("array_3")
    @Expose
    private List<Array3Item> arraylist3 = null;

   //other getter setter

}
```

**The problem now** is I want to know how many array is inside `field_2` object. Look like there is no way for me to access the `field_2` object.

I try to access it via `field2.names()` , but it cant resolve.

Therefore someone please help.

**What I want is**, How many key like `array 1`, `array 2` is existed inside `field_2`? It will return a value in `int`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
try {
    int total=0;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(field_2);
    Iterator<String> temp = json.keys();
    while (temp.hasNext()) {
        // do your other stuffs here
        total=total+1; //at last you will get total objects in field_2

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OR

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject (field_2_jsonObject);
JSONArray keys = object.names ();

//KEYS SIZE WILL YOUR TOTAL LENGTH IN "field_2"
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length (); i++) {
     String key = keys.getString (i); // Here's your key

 }
```

Hope this will work... :)

Comment: hey bro, field2, I already make it as Field2 class, therefore if I use `new JSONObject(field2)` it cant resolve, any other way?

Comment: new JSONObject(field2) here, get field2 as Jsonobject manually, not class. Do JSON parsing manually for test, by doing manually you will get field_2 JSONObject and then pass it as in my answer.

Comment: the problem now is, I use Retrofit, which direct using the class to parse the whole json, so means that I have to manually parse it again??

Comment: @ken yes, because if you passed your model class to retrofit request, it will automatically save your response in model class. But here you want to get total count of objects in your field_2. So you need to pass JsonObject to get response and after you get response in jsonobject, try as my answer

Answer (score 0):

lets say that your array object like this

```
public class MyObject {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
// other getter and setter
}
```

so the parsing will be using Gson with retrofit like this

```
public class MyPojo {

    @SerializedName("field_1")
    @Expose
    private Field1 class1;

    @SerializedName("field_2")
    @Expose
    private Field2 class2;

    @SerializedName("field_3")
    @Expose
    private Field3 class3;
    // other getter and setter

}

public class Field2 {
private Map<String,List<MyObject>> map=new HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();
// other getter and setter

}
```

so the point here is that you don't know how many keys will be like array_1,array_2, ... etc , so you use a map of string which is the key , and the value is your json Object

you can check [link1](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-maps), [link2](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serialize-deserialize-hashmap/)

Comment: bro can you give more example about the HashMap?? Cause I not understand what it will be use

Comment: I think you missunderstood, what I want is, I want to know how many keys is inside the `field2`,like it return in `int`

Comment: you can get this easily using `map.size()` if your keys are unique you can use [Set](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-sets)

Comment: `<List<MyObject>>` the `MyObject` is the class that contain `Field2 ` class? and I add the  `map` in `Field2` class?

Comment: Can I know what is the point for create in `Field2` class? can I use anywhere else?

Comment: as your `Field2`class are json object you need a class the represent it, if this doesn't work try replacing `Field2` in your MyPojo class directly with the map

Comment: it always return 0.. I dont know why

Comment: I think there is an issue with parsing , could you edit the post and post the whole response , so we can figure out where is the issue