# How I may fit retrofit response in HashMap?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I would like to "fit" retrofit response in HashMap (because I believe that I have to). How do I make it? I've tried to extend the Rates class, but doesn't help at all. Just get stuck here, and don't have pretty much any idea how to get out of here...

**JSON response**

```
    {
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.5495,
    "HKD": 9.1925,
    "ISK": 164.5,
    "PHP": 57.665,
    "DKK": 7.4412,
    "HUF": 358.77,
    "CZK": 26.338,
    "AUD": 1.6171,
    "RON": 4.8423,
    "SEK": 10.3065,
    "IDR": 17489.04,
    "INR": 86.8225,
    "BRL": 6.4205,
    "RUB": 88.0675,
    "HRK": 7.5335,
    "JPY": 126.0,
    "THB": 37.095,
    "CHF": 1.0799,
    "SGD": 1.6153,
    "PLN": 4.4186,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "TRY": 8.7588,
    "CNY": 8.0976,
    "NOK": 10.406,
    "NZD": 1.7541,
    "ZAR": 19.9154,
    "USD": 1.1861,
    "MXN": 25.915,
    "ILS": 3.9901,
    "GBP": 0.8884,
    "KRW": 1408.07,
    "MYR": 4.9176
  },
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2020-09-02"
}
```

**Api**

```
public interface ApiCall {
    @GET("latest")
    Call<CurrencyModel> getRates();
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class CurrencyModel {

@SerializedName("rates")
private Rates rates;

public Rates getRates() {
    return rates;
}



class Rates{
    @SerializedName("CAD")
    public Double cAD;
    @SerializedName("HKD")
    public Double hKD;
    @SerializedName("ISK")
    public Double iSK;
    @SerializedName("PHP")
    public Double pHP;
    @SerializedName("DKK")
    public Double dKK;
    @SerializedName("HUF")
    public Double hUF;
    @SerializedName("CZK")
    public Double cZK;
    @SerializedName("AUD")
    public Double aUD;
    @SerializedName("RON")
    public Double rON;
    @SerializedName("SEK")
    public Double sEK;
    @SerializedName("IDR")
    public Double iDR;
    @SerializedName("INR")
    public Double iNR;
    @SerializedName("BRL")
    public Double bRL;
    @SerializedName("RUB")
    public Double rUB;
    ...
```

**View class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiCall call = retrofit.create(ApiCall.class);
        
        call.getRates().enqueue(new Callback<CurrencyModel>  () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CurrencyModel> call, Response<CurrencyModel> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: error " + response.code());
                }

                HashMap<String, Double> map = response.body().getRates();

            }
                @Override
                public void onFailure (Call <CurrencyModel> call, Throwable t){
                    Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by retrofit?

Comment: retrofit is a http client library. if i understand the question... i believe OP would like to receive a deserialized rate map. that way rates.get("CAD") would return the appropriate value? is this correct?

Comment: After getting correctly the response. I want to get keys (such as CAD,HKD etc), and values (value of those currencies) and place it into the Map<String, Double>

Comment: make your Rates class have `Map<String,Double> map=new HashMap<String,Double>();` , also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645886/how-to-get-how-many-key-inside-a-gson-object-model-class-android/63646587#63646587) thread which might be similar

Comment: in that case you need parsing the object one by one, `map.put(yourString, response.body().getRates().cAD); map.put(yourString, response.body().getRates(). hKD);`